# IOS HTTP Post Creating and handling response

Tags: ios, http, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to refactor some code I had used in Phonegap Javascript that was uploading an Audio File to IOS Objective C and I'm a bit lost.

The code in JavaScript is as follows:

```
function uploadToClypit(file){
    console.log(file);

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.name = file.fullPath.substr(file.fullPath.lastIndexOf('/')+ 1);
    options.audioFile = file.nativeURL;
    options.fileName = file.nativeURL;
    options.mimeType = "audio/wav";
    options.headers = {
        Connection: "close"
    }
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    console.log(options);

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    console.log(file.nativeURL);
    ft.upload(file.nativeURL, encodeURI("http://upload.clyp.it/upload"), win, failUpload, options);

}
```

And the response is handled like this:

```
var win = function(r){
    var jsontext = r.response;
    var json = JSON.parse(jsontext);
    console.log(json);

}
```

So in IOS I am trying to create a HTTP Post Request, append an Audio File to the HTTP Body, send in some other text parameters and then handle the response.

I've done this so far.

1. Set my controller to implement the
2. Set up a NSMutableData variable *_responseData to hold the response

I create the HTTP request by doing the following:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                    initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://upload.clyp.it/upload"]]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";
    NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];
    [request addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

     NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file upload\"; filename=\"uploadaudio.mp3\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: audio/m4a\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];




    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];
    ICIRecordingCell *c = (ICIRecordingCell *)cell;
    NSString *fileName = c.title.text;
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSData *audioData;

    audioData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [postBody appendData:audioData];
     [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

     [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    [request setHTTPBody:postBody];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And then I am trying to set up the delegate methods to handle the response:

```
    #pragma mark NSURLConnection Delegate Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    // A response has been received, this is where we initialize the instance var you created
    // so that we can append data to it in the didReceiveData method
    // Furthermore, this method is called each time there is a redirect so reinitializing it
    // also serves to clear it
    _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
    [_responseData appendData:data];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    // Return nil to indicate not necessary to store a cached response for this connection
    return nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // The request is complete and data has been received
    // You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now
    NSString *d = (NSString *)_responseData;
    NSLog(d);

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // The request has failed for some reason!
    // Check the error var
}
```

When I look at what is being returned into the _responseData I'm not really sure what to do with it>

> Printing description of self->_responseData: <7b224d65 73736167
>   65223a22 416e2065 72726f72 20686173 206f6363 75727265 642e227d>

I'm also not really sure if I've set up the request properly - I've just borrowed code that I've found here  on StackOverflow without fully understanding it.

Any pointers direction more than welcome

Comment: I suggest using some of the existing libraries, as they have already this logic implemented. I have best experience with AfNetworking - https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: But if you want to do it on your own, you need to decode data in connectionDidFinishLoading, if you have JSON format, use this NSDictionary *jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error]; to save your request into dictionary

Comment: Excellent thanks - I had thought to use ASIHTTPRequest but then I read somewhere that it was not being actively supported anymore.  Will try AfNetworking.  Thanks

Comment: Np :) You will find afnetworking easy to use, if you get any problem, let me know, I'll try to help :)

Comment: @Yanchi I'm wondering if you could take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856145/using-afnetworking-to-upload-an-audio-file - the CompletionHandler isn't firing and I can't figure out if I'm sending the request properly.  thanks